# How to update json file with python -c flag?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This works in python shell, but not when I execute it with `python -c`, what is the syntax error here?

I need to update just one value in file `myjson.json`

```
python3.6 -c "import json; with open('myjson.json', 'r+') as jsonFile:  data = json.load(jsonFile); data['root']['target']['branch'][0] = 'updated_value'; jsonFile.seek(0); json.dump(data, jsonFile, indent=4); jsonFile.truncate()"
  File "<string>", line 1
    import json; with open('myjson.json', 'r+') as jsonFile:  data = json.load(jsonFile);  data['root']['target']['branch'][0] = 'updated_value'; jsonFile.seek(0); json.dump(data, jsonFile, indent=4); jsonFile.truncate()
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: It is surely preferable from the maintainability point of view to write the program into a file and execute the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax of Python is pretty much married to indent, and does not work well on a single line. In particular, many statements, including `with` and `if`, cannot have any other statements before them (specifically, I believe any statement that indents, i.e. that has a trailing colon). Thus, this is invalid, whether in Python shell, Python script or `-c` argument:

```
a = 1; if a == 1: print(a)
```

It must be written as

```
a = 1
if a == 1: print(a)
```

or

```
a = 1
if a == 1:
    print(a)
```

If you want to pass such a program from shell, you have to pass a newline into the `-c` parameter. For example, in `bash`:

```
python3 -c $'a = 1\nif a == 1: print(a)'
```

(The bash syntax `$'...'` quotes a string in such a way that control sequences such as `\n` are recognised.)

EDIT: This is the literal answer to the question. DYZ is absolutely correct in the comment that it is not a great practice trying to mash Python into a one-liner. Making a script file makes sense. If for whatever reason you can't, using a heredoc will massively improve readability:

```
cat << EOF | python3
a = 1
if a == 1:
    print(a)
EOF
```

EDIT2: There are better tools to update a value in a JSON file, if you are okay with not doing it with Python. The easiest one is `jq`, a tool whose whole reason of existence is manipulating JSON:

```
jq '.root.target.branch[0] = "updated_value"' myjson.json
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @Amadan, I have another problem to solve using `jq`, if possible, can you please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/64144681/2748513 thank you.