# Updating key of json based on another key name using jq

Tags: json, bash, shell, jq

I have below json file, need to replace `tbd-` with `premium-` in task's value if and only if made is `german` and task's value starts with `tbd-`

```
{
    "vehicle": {
        "maintenance": [
            {
                "parts": "wheel",
                "size": ["one", "two"]
            },
            {
                "task": "tbd-service-oil",
                "car": {
                    "german": {
                        "audi": ["Synthetic"]
                    }
                },
                "some": ["other"]
            },
            {
                "task": "service-oil",
                "honda": {
                    "japan": {
                        "oil": ["regular"]
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "repair": [
            {
                "parts": "wheel",
                "size": ["one", "two"]
            },
            {
                "task": "tbd-engine-repair",
                "car": {
                    "german": {
                        "engine": ["6-cyl"]
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "task": "engine-repair",
                "car": {
                    "german": {
                        "engine": ["4-cyl"]
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
        
    }
}
```

need to update above json file to:

```
{
    "vehicle": {
        "maintenance": [
            {
                "parts": "wheel",
                "size": ["one", "two"]
            },
            {
                "task": "premium-service-oil", ## update this b'cos there is "german" under "car" and task's value had prefix "tbd-"
                "car": {
                    "german": {
                        "audi": ["Synthetic"]
                    }
                },
                "some": ["other"]
            },
            {
                "task": "service-oil",
                "honda": {
                    "japan": {
                        "oil": ["regular"]
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "repair": [
            {
                "parts": "wheel",
                "size": ["one", "two"]
            },
            {
                "task": "premium-engine-repair", ## update this b'cos there is "german" under "car" and task's value had prefix "tbd-"
                "car": {
                    "german": {
                        "engine": ["6-cyl"]
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "task": "engine-repair", ### no need to update this as it don't have "tbd-" as prefix
                "car": {
                    "german": {
                        "engine": ["4-cyl"]
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
        
    }
}
```

so far, I tried to get all the keys with `german` as keyname, I am not successful though

```
jq -c 'to_entries[] | select (.key.maintenance.car == "german") | [.key]' json
jq: error (at json:50): Cannot index string with string "maintenance"
```

I could query the `parts` matching `wheel`, using similar command

```
$ jq -c 'to_entries[] | select (.value.maintenance[0].parts == "wheel") | [.key]'  json
["vehicle"]
```

UPDATE:

I am okay to skip checking if key has `tbd-`, I can go update all the key names irrespective of prefix.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiast programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18592173/select-objects-based-on-value-of-variable-in-object-using-jq this was the closest I could find, I am reading through `jq` documentation, but it's being very hard for me to grasp, just started with jq.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution using `walk`. If for some reason you want a more targeted solution (for example, one that does not use `walk`), it should be easy to modify it accordingly.

```
walk( if type=="object" and .task and (.task|startswith("tbd-")) and
         any(.[]; type=="object" and has("german"))
      then .task|=sub("tbd-"; "premium-")
      else . end )
```

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot use walk as its not installed on all servers, jq is installed on all.

Comment: @rodee - Simply prepend the def of walk to the jq program. You can do that even if jq already defines it.

Comment: will you be able to help with https://stackoverflow.com/q/64213506/2748513 thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have jq 1.6 , which has walk/1 , do prepend the def walk :

```
jq '
# Apply f to composite entities recursively, and to atoms
    def walk(f):
    . as $in
    | if type == "object" then
        reduce keys[] as $key
            ( {}; . + { ($key):  ($in[$key] | walk(f)) } ) | f
    elif type == "array" then map( walk(f) ) | f
    else f
    end;
  walk( if type=="object" and .task and (.task|startswith("tbd-")) and any(.[]; type=="object" and has("german")) then .task|=sub("tbd-"; "premium-") else . end )
' filename
```

source: https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/963#issuecomment-152783116