# How to conditionally select array index to update based on value

Tags: json, shell, select, jq

I have a json file as below, need to append the new name into `.root.application.names`, but if the name passed in has prefix (everything before `-`, in below example it's `jr`), then find the list with same prefix names already present, and update it, if there is only one names list or if there is no matching list, then update first list.

In the below example, if

`$application == 'application1' and $name == <whatever>; just update first list under application1, as there is only one list under application1, nothing to choose from.`

`$application == 'application2' and if $name has no prefix delimiter "-" or unmatched prefix (say sr-allen); then update the first list under application2.names, because foo has no or unmatched prefix.`

`$application == 'application2' and say $name == jr-allen; then update the second list under application2, because $name has prefix "jr-" and there is a list with items matching this prefix.`

```
{
    "root": {
        "application1": [
            {
                "names": [
                    "john"
                ],
                "project": "generic"
            }
        ],
        "application2": [
            {
                "names": [
                    "peter",
                    "jack"
                ],
                "project": "generic"
            },
            {
                "names": [
                    "jr-sam",
                    "jr-mike",
                    "jr-rita"
                ],
                "project": "junior-project"
            }
         ]
     }
}
```

I found how to update the list, not sure how to add these conditions, any help please?

`jq '."root"."application2"[1].names[."root"."application2"[1].names| length] |= . + "jr-allen"' foo.json`

Update:
good if I can do this with jq/walk, I am still trying as below, but couldn't get anywhere close.

```
prefix=$(echo ${name} | cut -d"-" -f1) # this gives the prefix, e.g: "jr"
jq -r --arg app "${application}" name "${name}" prefix "${prefix}"'
    def walk(f):
    . as $in
    | if type == "object" then
        reduce keys[] as $key
            ( {}; . + { ($key):  ($in[$key] | walk(f)) } ) | f
    elif type == "array" then map( walk(f) ) | f
    else f
    end;
  walk( if type=="object" and ."$app" and (.names[]|startswith("$prefix")) ) then .names[]="$name" else . end )
' foo.json
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me a while to have any confidence that I have understood the requirements, but I believe the following at least captures the essence of what you have in mind.

To make the solution easier to understand, we begin with a helper function, the name of which makes its purpose clear enough, at least given the context:

```
def updateFirstNamesArrayWithMatchingPrefix($prefix; $value):
  (first( range(0; length) as $i
          | if any(.[$i].names[]; startswith($prefix))
            then $i else empty end) // 0) as $i
  | .[$i].names += [$value] ;

  
.root |=
  if .[$app] | length == 1 
  then .[$app][0].names += [ $name ]
  elif .[$app] | length > 1
  then 
    ( $name | split("-")) as $components
    | if $components|length==1  # no prefix
      then .[$app][0].names += [ $name  ]
      else ($components[0] + "-" ) as $prefix
      | .[$app] |= updateFirstNamesArrayWithMatchingPrefix($prefix; $name)
      end
  else .
  end
```

### Testing

The above passes the four tests originally proposed by
@Inian:

```
jq --arg app "application1" --arg name "foo" -f script.jq jsonFile
jq --arg app "application2" --arg name "jr-foo" -f script.jq jsonFile
jq --arg app "application2" --arg name "sr-foo" -f script.jq jsonFile
jq --arg app "application2" --arg name "foo" -f script.jq jsonFile
```

### Herrings?

Based on my understanding of the problem, it seems to me that `walk` may be a bit of a red herring, but if not, I hope you'll be able to adapt the above to meet your actual requirements.

Comment: Works Great, thank you, is there a way to make the output `un_sorted`? I am a beginner in using jq, sorry if this a basic thing.

Comment: I use jq-1.5 version, not sure how to use `keys_unsorted/0` in the above function

Comment: The jq program does not do any sorting, and I do not understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is: If prefix exists in name, update the last array element, else the first one.

When the array has one element, like for `application1`, the last is the first also.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

application="$1"
name="$2"
json_file="file.json"
ind=0

# if name matches "-", set index to the last array element
[[ "$name" == *"-"* ]] && ind=-1

jq --arg app "$application" \
   --arg name "$name" \
   --argjson ind "$ind" \
   '.root[$app][$ind].names += [$name]' "$json_file"
```

I believe above script is self-explanatory enough, `--argjson` used for having an unquoted index, `+=` stands for `|= . +`.

---

### Testing

Commands below produce the expected result.

```
bash test.sh application1 jr-John
bash test.sh application2 jr-John
bash test.sh application1 Mary
bash test.sh application2 Mary
```

Comment: Thanks @thanasisp, but this don't work if I have more than 2 lists with different prefix. thanks for your reply.

Comment: Obviously, as your description and your example say that for every object, there is one array with names, and one with prefixed names. If you have many arrays with many different prefixes, it would have been great if you had included that into your sample case.